# Redirect by .htaccess doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I want the URL www.michelenerna.nl to be redirected to www.michelenerna.nl/wycliffe.

The actual Joomla path is /wycliffe = 
http://www.michelenerna.nl/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=97&Itemid=249

So, I thought: the following lines in .htaccess should be appropriate, but it doesn't work. www.michelenerna.nl still directs to www.michelenerna.nl

This is the code:

```
Options SymlinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.michelenerna.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^article(.*)$ http://www.michelenerna.nl/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=97&Itemid=249/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: do you have access to the cPanel?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?michelenerna.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wycliffe/index.php [L]
```

You can also achieve this in the your server cPanel by going to the "Redirect" page and selecting the options that apply to you.

Comment: no, because 'wycliffe' is not a folder. I'm using joomla which deals with articles and then uses 1 index.php.
Your other solution doesn't work either, since www.michelenerna.nl is an alias for www.jmpauw.nl and I only want www.michelenerna.nl be directed to www.michelenerna.nl/wycliffe, while www.jmpauw.nl remains being directed to www.jmpauw.nl

Comment: note: any dots in a regular expression that are not enclosed in a character class `[]` or preceded by a backslash are treated as "wildcard characters" (any non-newline character).  It is a good habit to escape dots to make them literal -- even if it doesn't effect _this_ case.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?michelenerna.nl$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wycliffe [L]
```

Comment: No, than I get an infinite loop, because you redirect to another article, but to the same index.php.

Comment: If `wycliffe` is a valid folder under `root` folder it works. I used it a few times already! and about an infinite loop - it might happen only if you preform another redirect somewhere: either in `.htaccess` or in `index.php`